# Set a 2-line title on a UINavigationItem on iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I want to set a UINavigationItem's title such that it displays a 2 line title with both lines in a smaller font than normal.  I've definitely seen this effect on other apps such as Mail, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

I tried setting a prompt, that's definitely not what I want, I want the Nav Bar to stay the same height but have the text get smaller and allow two lines.

Is this possible by default or do I need my own custom view to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline Navigationbar Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298383/multiline-navigationbar-title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than setting the `Prompt`, what you are looking for is a custom `navigationBar` with a `UILabel` setting the `numberOfLines` property to 2. Alternatively, you can use 2 `UILabel`'s.

Comment: @RobLourens and @WrightsCS how do I know what to set the frame to?  (For example, this has to work on all iOS devices etc..).  Also, the font and color looks completely different ..

Comment: Set your `AutoResizingMasks`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `titleView` to a custom view, for example a UILabel with the desired font. To make it a 2-line label, make sure you set `numberOfLines` to 2.

Comment: Right, 0 will let the UILabel have any number of lines. I was just thinking that since I think that's the only thing I've used it for myself...