# Multiline Navigationbar Title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, swift3

I am trying to set the title label in my navigation bar to allow multiple lines. I have custom navigation controller code that I am placing the multiline code into. I know that the code already there works, but my multiline part is not working.

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationBar.frame.width, self.navigationBar.frame.height * 2)
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping

navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

But the text still runs off at the end. I've also tried putting this into the individual view controller itself, adding `self.navigationController?.` in front of `navigationItem` with the same results.

Is there something I'm missing in my code that would keep the title label from using multiple lines?

Comment: Your `navigationBar.frame.width` was maybe not yet sized to fit the screen. You may want to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to detect the right frame.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is a code example of how you can create a multiline navigationBar title

```
let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 50))
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16.0)
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
label.text = "This is a\nmultiline string for the navBar"
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

**Swift 5.x:**

```
let label = UILabel()
label.backgroundColor = .clear
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.textColor = .white
label.text = "This is a\nmultiline string for the navBar"
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

Comment: Gonna require some tweaking to get it to behave more like how I want it to, but this did help.

Comment: I used `navigationItem.titleView` without setting the frame explicitly and it is working just fine.

Comment: @Rashwan L if you are define the frame of UILabel it will lead to the label to the left align so just leave the frame part and use as just a "let label = UILabel()". and it will work perfect and set its own self in the center aligned.

Comment: Why width 400points?

Comment: let label = UILabel() this is the best solution to centre title!

Answer (score 4):

This is doable in a storyboard.  Just drag a UIView into the Navigation bar, then drag a UILabel onto it in the document outline, set lines to 2 and alignment to center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the label position exactly as you want it:

```
let labelWidth = navBar.bounds.width - 110

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:(navBar.bounds.width/2) - (labelWidth/2), y:0, width:labelWidth, height:navBar.bounds.height))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    label.text = loadedName
    navBar.topItem?.title = nil
    navBar.addSubview(label)
```

the 110 value in the top line is the spacing you want either side of the label.

Comment: any hints on doing this in swiftui?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your ViewController

```
navigationItem.setValue(1, forKey: "__largeTitleTwoLineMode")
```

Comment: private API probably isn't the best way to go

Answer (score -1):

swift 5+ very easy solution

```
func titleMultiLine(topText: String, bottomText: String) {
    //            let titleParameters = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
    //                                   NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.<Font>]
//            let subtitleParameters = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.<Color>(),
    //                                      NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.<Font>]
    let titleParameters = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    
    let subtitleParameters = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    
    let title:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: topText, attributes: titleParameters)
    let subtitle:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: bottomText, attributes: subtitleParameters)
    
    title.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
    title.append(subtitle)
    
    let size = title.size()
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    titleLabel.attributedText = title
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

Function Calling

```
self.titleMultiLine(topText: "I am top text Title", bottomText: "bottom text")
```