# Padding/Margin between Header title and right button bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that has Navigation controller and a  title. The width of title may vary. It could be short or too long. It comes from server.  I have logout button on the right side. I am adding all these things to Navigation Controller programatically.

But when the title is too long, it gets clipped in back button and right bar button.  It is shown below

[image]

Is there any way to make the title to get padding from back and logout button ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298383/multiline-navigationbar-title

Comment: @KarthickRamesh the problem is little changed. I have back and rightbar button

Comment: Is it fine in your case if the nav title goes for multiple line in the nav bar?

Comment: yes. but I do not want it to get cut off in back button and right bar button which is logout

Comment: @KarthickRamesh do you have any solution