# Multiline label on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

```
extension UINavigationItem {
        func setTitle(title:String) {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 16)
            label.backgroundColor = .clear
            label.numberOfLines = 2
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.textColor = UIColor(hex: "4E4E4E")
            label.text = title
            self.titleView = label
        }
    }
```

I have used the above code for displaying multiline label in navigation bar but it won't work on iPhone 6s+ particularly the label is cropped at the end (single line is displayed). which runs on 11.4.1.   I also have iPhone 7 which runs on 11.4 which does not have problem to display the multiline label. only thing is iPhone 6s+.  Could you please correct me if I missed anything

I tried steps explained here too [Multiline Navigationbar Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298383/multiline-navigationbar-title/51947218#51947218)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like this steps you followed, had given to you warning for same device in which you are having issue,

Comment: You can also use a xib file to do what you want, then add this line of code: `navigationItem.titleView = customView`

Comment: @SachinVsSachin I haven't got any issue

Comment: @AliMoazenzadeh, yeah I can use XIB, but same code works on iPhone 7 not in iPhone 6s+.  just want to know the reason. thanks

Comment: I have test your code and it worked even on 6s+, where you call this function?

Comment: can you please share screenshot for the same?

Comment: @AliMoazenzadeh in viewDidAppear method