# My navigation bar's large title is too large getting truncate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using navigation controller, and I've set to true its navigation bar's prefersLargeTitle property. Everything works fine, but when the text of my title is too large, it doesn't fit in space. Here how it looks:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okezg.png)

Is it possible to somehow make the title in multiline without changing its size.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to assign a new multi-line UILabel to navigationItem.titleView please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298383/multiline-navigationbar-title